# Which Internet Explorer versions are still Supported by Microsoft?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

Do you know where I can find any information regarding which Internet Explorer versions still are supported by Microsoft and hence still are getting vulnerability upgrades?

We are looking into if it is worth to upgrade from IE7 to IE8 within the coming year or if it is easier to wait for our windows 7 upgrade and start using IE9 directly.

What I would like to find is any articles describing the benefits and drawbacks of IE8 compared to IE7 with regards to security support. If Microsoft have released any information regarding the level of support they have for the different versions and so on. If they have released any information regarding when they are going to stop supporting the different versions etc.

Thank You

Comment: If you're looking for simply which application to use on your computer, IE8 is faster and has better standards support.

If you're looking for which browser to code for, code according to standards and as soon as you hear "browser specific" run for your life.

Answer (score 2):

Updates to Internet Explorer are tied to the version of the Windows operating system, as mentioned in [this blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/lifecycle/archive/2009/06/27/the-support-lifecycle-for-internet-explorer.aspx). Quoted:

> Internet Explorer is considered as a component of the operating system (OS) for which it was released. The support timelines for IE are inherited from the OS and its associated service packs. Basically, this means that the versions of Internet Explorer that shipped for a specific OS or service pack will be supported with the support lifecycle of the OS or service pack. Support for older versions of IE will not end unless we ship a replacement version of IE in a future OS service pack.

However, Windows Vista and Windows 7 have not been given an support end date. You may want to look out for any announcements from Microsoft ending support for any of these OSes, and upgrade accordingly.